# Ogre3D Tutorial Framework - how to build ois and where to find SDKTrays.h

Tags: c++, compilation, ogre

Shortly I started using ogre3D. I found tutorials for it on ogres wikipage: (http://wiki.ogre3d.org/Basic+Tutorials).

The problem is that the framework provieded on their website uses ois, so I tried to compile ois, but I am getting the error that the function virtual KeyCode getAsKeyCode( std::string str ) {/*TODO: Implement OS version*/;} must return something. (This is a function writen by ois.

Does anyone now how I can fix this bug?

My second problem is that the framework is including some files from ogre which I never have seen before. For example it includes SDKTrays.h. Does anyone know where I can get these files from?

Here are the programs with versions I am using:

Ogre 1.10.8
Visual Studio 2017

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: How did you obtain OIS for your build? I found it easier to compile everything by downloading the dependencies [from the Ogre3D repository](https://bitbucket.org/sinbad/ogre/src/cae8d7e7af248ea7c9dedaf95f48aca684ee7bbd/BuildingOgre.md?fileviewer=file-view-default). The same is also available [via Github](https://github.com/OGRECave/ogre/blob/master/BuildingOgre.md). I see now that its been updated; by default ogre will build the essential dependencies automatically.

Comment: I got ois from their github page. The folder included already the sln-file and when I compiled the ois-project the i got the error explained above. The rest of the dependencies was compiled perfectly, for example freeType.

Comment: Found this on the [ogre3d forum](http://forums.ogre3d.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=92884): OIS was replaced with SDL2 for 1.10 - if you use the Bites Component, you should no longer need it.

Comment: Even more explicit: [OIS is depreciated, Ogre uses SDL2 for input now. Ignore it.](http://forums.ogre3d.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=93454)

Comment: Okay. Do you know if there is a good tutorial for ogre 1.10.x. I just can find tutorials for ogre 1.9 and this seems to work completely different.

Comment: Yes it can be confusing. But I think it will work if you [follow the tutorial](http://wiki.ogre3d.org/Ogre+Wiki+Tutorial+Framework) and take note of the 1.10 recommended [OgreBites::ApplicationContext](https://ogrecave.github.io/ogre/api/1.10/setup.html#skeleton) and replace that where appropriate.

Comment: So you mean I don't need this baseApplication.h (the framework stuff), but I just have to write the class for ogreBites?

Comment: Seems like the best way would be to start [here](https://ogrecave.github.io/ogre/api/1.10/tutorials.html).  1.10.9 has the [Samples/Tutorial directory](https://github.com/OGRECave/ogre/tree/master/Samples/Tutorials).

Comment: Can you try formatting the code inside your answer?